# Applying Zorn's lemma to the set of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a ring, and $B$ is finitely generated faithful $A$-module.

Let $Γ$＝｛N｜N is submodule of B and B/N is faithful A-mod｝

I want to show $Γ$ has maximal element with Zorn's Lem.

I only need to show that every chain of $Γ$ has upper bound・・・①

But I do not know how to show ①.

According to my text book, ① is obvious because

$N∈Γ$⇔｛$ab1,・・・,abn$｝⇒$a＝0$ for all $a∈A$ ・・・②

（$B$ is finitely generatedly module over $A$,so we denote $B$＝$Ab1＋・・・＋Abn$）

But I don't know why this is obvious.
I think ② is obvious but ②⇒① is not obvious.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}= \{N_i: i \in I\}$ be a chain in $\Gamma$. Put $$N:= \bigcup_{i \in I} N_i$$
Since we have a chain, $N$ is a submodule of $B$. Moreover, $B/N$ is faithful. To see this, assume $x \in A$ satisfies $xB \subseteq N$. We must show that $x = 0$.

With your notation, let $B$ be generated as an $A$-module by $b_1, \dots, b_n$. Then because we have a chain, there is $i \in I$ with $xb_j \in N_i$ for all $j =1, \dots, n$ and consequently $x B \subseteq N_i$. Since $B/N_i$ is faithful, necessarily $x= 0$.

Hence, $N$ is an upper bound for the chain $\mathcal{C}$.